# API 28 VS 29: что лучше?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Сразу говорю, я слабо разбираюсь в API и какая между ними разница. С 1 августа в Google Play новые приложения должны быть с API 28.
в IDEA есть возможность поставить API 29.

Но я так понял, что это не финальная ее версия, а еще Beta 5 ?

Будут ли еще что-то сделать с API 28 или это финальная?

Лучше начать новое приложение на 28 или 29 ?

Comment: С августа 2019 года целевая версия новых приложений должна быть не менее Android 9.0 (API уровня 28).
С ноября 2019 года целевая версия обновляемых приложений должна быть не менее Android 9.0 (API уровня 28).

Comment: @Alex и зачем вы продублировали мой вопрос? какая тут полезная или новая информация? это даже не комментарий, не то чтобы ответ.

Comment: Интересно, а какой мин. api в 23 году актуален.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое разумное решение - ставить максимальную стабильную версию. Так у вас должно всё работать на всех девайсах.

Ставить бета-версии нужно только если вы хотите заранее выяснить что там надо будет править, чтобы когда она станет стабильной - не изучать это в спешке.

Без проверки всё ли у вас работает на новой версии API выкладывать приложение опасно. Часто выходят ломающие изменения, которые, при этом, не активируются, если у вас стоит не последняя версия API.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать 28. К 29 могли подъехать не все androidx библиотеки, например, могут быть баги и прочие радости жизни, все же бета. А плюсов для рядового разработчика нет. Когда выйдет новый андроид и плеймаркет скажет, что не хочет кушать ничего ниже 29 - переедите на 29, этот процесс проходит без проблем в подавляющем большинстве случаев

Answer (score 2):

API 28 это текущая (последняя на данный момент) стабильная версия Android. API 29, это уже следующая версия, которая должна выйти.

> Лучше начать новое приложение на 28 или 29 ?

Лучше сначала определиться, для для кого и для каких устройств или целей Вы пишете приложение, а заодно прикинуть сколько потребуется времени на разработку.

Если это учебное приложение, то без разницы. Можно даже начать сразу на API 29, чтобы присмотреться к новинкам (ИМХО).

Если же это какое-то рабочее приложение, то однозначно API 28, т.к. эта версия стабильна, а в бете ещё может быть много неприятных неожиданностей (баги и т.п.). Плюс вероятно придётся подождать пока для API 29 выйдут совместимые обновления библиотек и т.д.

P.S. Кроме того, я что-то сомневаюсь, что Вам позволят выложить приложение на основе сырого API (опять же моё ИМХО).